# C Program to convert centimeters to inches and feet

Tags: c

I am trying to write a c program to convert centimeters to inches and then to feet. I have most of the code written but not sure how to debug it. I keep getting "0" as all of my output. Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Main Function
int main(void)
{
    //Variable declarations
    int centimeters = 0 ;
    int inches = 0;
    int feet = 0;

    /* ... */

     // Print a title
    printf("Convert centimeters to inches and feet\n");

    {
        printf("Input Length in Centimeters: "); // Prompt user for input
        scanf("%i", & centimeters);  // Get input form user for length in cm
    }

    // conversion calcs
    inches = (double)centimeters * 2.54;
    feet = (double) inches / 12;

    /* ... */

    //  Print output
    printf("Statistics:\n");
    printf("centimeters%12f\n", centimeters);
    printf("inches%12f\n", inches);
    printf("feet%12f\n", feet);

    /* ... */

    return 0;
```

Comment: Integer division. Replace that 12 by a 12.0 Oh and declare your variables double, not int.

Comment: Could you try to declare `inches`, `feet` and `centimeters` as `float` instead of `int` ? `int` stands for integer. And `scanf("%g",&centimeters);`

Comment: Bob - you can't mix and match different `types` (e.g. `int`, `double`, `float`) in arithmetic without either understanding promotion or casting as necessary. In this case jumbling `int`, `float`, and `double` together in your conversion calculations is simply causing you unnecessary headaches. Pick 1, either `float` or `double` and stick with it. Life will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In C, types never change themselves. Even though you're assigning a floating point number to an integer, the integer will still be an integer. For an application like this, I would recommend you just make everything a floating point number.

```
//Variable declarations
int centimeters = 0 ;
int inches = 0;
int feet = 0;
```

should be

```
//Variable declarations
double centimeters = 0 ;
double inches = 0;
double feet = 0;
```

This will also allow your `printf` statements to keep on using `%f` to print the numbers. You will need to change your `scanf` statement to also use `%f` though.

As to why you were getting 0 as your results, it's actually pretty simple if you know how numbers are stored internally.

Most floating point implementations store the bits in this order: sign, exponent, mantissa. If your implementation is using 32 bit IEEE floats, the first 8 bits are used for the sign and exponent, and the last 24 are for the mantissa. This means that if your value fits completely within a single byte (between 0 and 255 inclusive) then it will be 0 if read as a float, as the mantissa will be completely empty.

This is because most Intel-based desktop computers store their bytes in little-endian format, which means the least significant byte comes first and the most significant is last. For example, in little-endian machines, a 32 bit number that represents these values would be stored like:

```
0x01: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00
0xFF: 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x1FF: 0xFF 0x01 0x00 0x00
0xA0F00D: 0x0D 0xF0 0xA0 0x00
And so on...
```

So if you have a value that's less than 0x100 (255 or lower) then it will only occupy the first byte of memory. It just so happens that the first 8 bytes of a 32 bit float do not hold any significant digits, so it will be treated as 0 if it's read as a float.

A 64 bit float (a double) uses the first 11 bits for its sign and exponent, so you can hide values all the way up to 2048 in there.

EDIT: Just an addendum, since someone up-voted this recently:

This post isn't totally incorrect, however I failed to mention the fact that there is an implicit leading bit which is set (a one, so to speak) in the mantissa if the exponent is not all zeros. When such is the case, it is called a normalized value, which can never be zero. Only if the number is denormalized (all the exponent bits are unset/zeroed out) can you have a true zero value.

If the user were to store a value between 0 and 15 or between 128 and 143 into the first 8 bits of a 32 bit float, that would give an exponent which would make the represented value so small that most display functions will round it to zero. This is because that would result in a very small exponent, as 0-15 only consume the lower 4 bits, and 128-143 are the same values with the most significant bit set (which may end up in the sign bit). The specific mapping depends on how the machine orders its bits.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format. Instead of `%12f`, use `%12d`.

```
printf("centimeters%12d\n", centimeters);
printf("inches%12d\n", inches);
printf("feet%12d\n", feet);
```

While it's true that you will lose fractional values, that might be your intention. However, passing an `int` to `printf` where a `double` is expected causes undefined behavior.

See the differences in the output when using `%12f` vs `%12d` at http://ideone.com/JdjE3z.

Comment: Changing the output formatting won't make a difference as long as the calculations are being done as integer arithmetic - see the other answers and comments.

Comment: @R Sahu - ideone.com is not using a C compiler.  It may be "compiling" C code, but the results it generates are not what a **C** compiler will produce.

Comment: @FKEinternet, I don't know which compiler you use but I saw the same results on my desktop, using gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: It sounds like the gcc compiler is pretty severely broken, then, because the C language definition says that integer math doesn't preserve fractional values, and since the OP's variables are defined as `int` values, there wouldn't be any fractional data for `printf` to format.

Comment: @FKEinternet, while it's true that you will lose fractional values, that might the OP's intention. However, passing an `int` to `printf` where a `double` is expected causes undefined behavior.

Comment: A right - that's a different question than what I was looking at.  Perhaps you should mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()

{
    float c = 0.0,i = 0.0;  //  c = centimeters, i = inches
    int f = 0;      //  f = feet

    printf("Input length in centimeter: ");
    scanf("%f",&c);

    f = (c / 2.54) / 12;
    i = (c / 2.54) - (f * 12);
    printf("%.1f centimeters is %d feet %.1f inches.\n",c,f,i);
    exit ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Although in general code-only answers are acceptable, it is usually a good idea to [edit] and add a short explanation of what is going on in the code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll do more comments in next time! Thanks for tip!